# How to prove that some statements are logically compatible?

Tags: logic

I have three people accused of tax fraud that claim the following:

- Dupont: Dupont is guilty and Martin is innocent,
- Legrand: if Dupont is guilty then Martin is guilty too.
- Martin: I'm innocent but at least one of the other two is guilty.

How can I show if these statements are compatible? And if everybody tells the truth, who is guilty?

I tried using a truth table:

Let be L: Legrand is guilty, D: Dupont  is guilty, M: Martin is guilty.

I know that from their statements we have:

- $D\rightarrow M$
- $L\wedge \neg M$
- $\neg M \wedge (L \vee D)$

Yet, when I compute it in a truth table I find,

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
L & D & M &\neg M & L\vee D & \neg M \wedge (L\vee D) & D \rightarrow M & L \wedge \neg M & the \ answer\\
\hline
T & T & T & F & T & T & T & F & F\\
T & F & T & F & T & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & T & F & T & T & T & F & F\\
F & F & T & F & F & F & F & F & F\\
T & T & F & T & T & T & T & T & F\\
T & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
F & T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F\\
F & F & F & T & F & F & F & F & F\\
\end{array}$$

Thus, it seems I have no case where the three statements are compatible since the only case where these statements are compatible is when two of them are false.

Further more, when each of them are right I don't know how to find who is guilty.

Comment: You're almost there.  Just think a bit more about the TFF line...

Comment: @mmw Haaaaaaaaaaa, okay I was maybe stuck in the table and didn't thought to step out. Does it means Legrand is guilty?